# Restrict a mimeType not to show in Storage Access Framework(SAF) document picker

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

Does SAF(Storage Access Framework) support filter not?
I want to filter the picker not to show `image/*` mimeType files.

In fact i want to let user pick any file `(*/*)` except `(image/*)` .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no option for that.

Comment: This is awful.. By the way, do you know any workaround for this? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/70028951/4397753)