# Setting the orientation of the system picker of Storage Access Framework (SAF)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-orientation, storage-access-framework

So far, I was using my own file browser for the best user experience, but as everyone knows, we are now forced to use **SAF** when accessing the shared storage.
I wouldn't mind using it if it offered everything I need, but it seems not.

I got first frustrated when I found there's no way to filter by extension. (My app's data is saved as **.cta**, which isn't supported by any other apps in the world.)

And today, I found the default orientation mode of the system picker is portrait.
It supports landscape mode too, but it's enabled only when a user rotates with the **Auto rotate** option on in their system settings. (I don't personally turn on that option, btw)

Also, we have to see the unnecessary portrait-to-landscape transition animation because the system picker always starts in portrait mode no matter what.
It doesn't care about the calling Activity's orientation at all.
The orientation attribute in the `<application>` tag is ignored as well.
I also tried working around it with `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` (to call `setRequestedOrientation()` at `onCreate()` of **SAF**) but only to fail.

Is there any way to open the system picker in landscape mode?

Comment: Are you sure that we could have control over other app's orientation change?

Comment: If you have Auto rotate off in your system settings, then it is **your activity** that is forcing the orientation to landscape, despite the user's preference to not rotate their display and it is in fact the SAF activity that is respecting the user's preference.

Comment: @hardik9850 If the SAF took some special arguments via `Intent`, we could. But the google document doesn't say anything about the orientation settings, so I had to ask here.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Regardless of the system settings, there has to be a way to control the SAF activity programmatically like via `Intent`. As a user, do you really want to browse in portrait mode, when the app/game you were using is in landscape mode? Whether it's the SAF activity or not, making users rotate their phones is awful.

Comment: I guess if SAF is not providing the choice to pass the orientation arg then our hands are tied.

Comment: @hardik9850 The guy above is from Google. If SAF doesn't provide the feature currently, we need to ask for that. It's very easy for them to add because SAF already supports landscape mode. We just need an option to control programmatically. Even the old browser implemented by me takes the orientation option via Intent. If Android keeps missing these kinds of small details, Android will never catch up with iOS in terms of smooth UX.

Comment: agree with you there.

Comment: @ianhanniballake No news on this yet? Is it really hard for you smart people from Google to add this orientation option? SAF already supports the landscape mode. We just want a way to set it manually because Android forced us to use SAF.

Comment: @Jenix - I'd encourage you to [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192705) that would actually get looked at by someone who actually works on SAF (which is *not* me). Commenting on StackOverflow is not a feature request and never has been.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I know commenting here (including this comment) won't help at all. I'd filed many times myself before I gave up. Unless it's a serious bug or some feature Google is really focusing on, most of them are just ignored. The reason why I asked you here is, you know better than me about the framework. I hoped there's some good news on it. Google is trying hard to copy iOS adding many restrictions. But they keep missing small details like this. There are reasons why many people (including Googlers) choose iOS over Android.

Comment: I've been a big fan and supporter of Android since day 1. I also reported and fixed many Android-related bugs of tools/plugins like Unity and FMOD for Android users. If Google keeps frustrating Android developers like this, it's not very good for Android in the long term. We've been making Android-only apps, but recently started developing iOS apps and immediately fell in love with the development environment and support there.